# why section-testimonial is not placing correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build the testimonial section but it's not placing orderly, it's placing within the services section. here's the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/Razu381/pen/XQJVzg

here is the code:

```
<div   class="section-testimonial">
  <div  class="row" >
      <div  class="col-md-2">
        <h2>  What people say about me</h2>
      </div>
      <div   class="col-md-10">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  </p> 
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove this css:

```
.section-services{
}
.services-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
}
```

check out my answer:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:300,400|Lato:300i,400|Pacifico|Tangerine:400,700&display=swap');
body{
 font-family: lato;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.header-text{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: Abril Fatface;
    color:#2ecc71;
}
.degrees{
 font-size: 20px;
}
.top-nav{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: lato;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link{
 color: black;
 margin: 3px;
}
.s-icon i{
 margin:3px;
}
/*----about me section---*/
.section-about{
 background: #f8f8f8;
    
}
.section-about h2{
 font-family: Abril Fatface;
 font-size: 40px!important;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 word-spacing: 4px;
}
.section-about h2{
 margin-top: 100px;
}
h2:after {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    content: "";
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.section-about p{
 margin-top: 30px;
}
/*----services section---*/

.section-services .card{
 background-color: #2ecc713d;
}
.section-services .card-header{
 background-color:#2ecc71; 
 text-align: center;
 margin:5px 0;
}

.section-services h2{
 font-family: Abril Fatface;
 font-size: 40px!important;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 word-spacing: 4px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 right: 50%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.section-services h2:after{
 width: 220px;
}
.section-services p{
 text-align: center;
}
.section-services .card-body img{
 max-width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 height: 150px;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
/*------section-testimonial---*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>homw</title>
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7ea1edf4c8.js"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab|Lato|Pacifico|Tangerine&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/367919f9b0.js"></script>
  <style>
    .carousel-item{
    height: 100vh;
} 
.carousel-item img{
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit:cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-family:Pacifico;font-size: 30px;color: #2ecc71;" href="#">DR. S. Faruqi</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto top-nav" >
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Testimonials</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Chembers</a>
    </div>
    
      <span class="s-icon">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x"><a href="fb.com" title=""></a></i>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x"><a href="fb.com" title=""></a></i>
        <i class="fab fa-youtube-square fa-2x"><a href="fb.com" title=""></a></i>
      </span>
  </div>
</nav>




    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height: 100vh;position: relative;">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/4" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="section-about">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-5">
       <h2>About Me</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/22" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="section-services "style="position:relative ;" >
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/5.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;height: 400px;">
  <h2>Services </h2>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="services-inner">
    <div class="row  services-overlay ">
     <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/6" alt="" class=" card-img-top " >
            <h4 class="card-header">Primary Treatment</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/7" alt="" class="card-img-top " >
            <h4 class="card-header">Primary Injury</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/8" alt="" class=" card-img-top " >
            <h4 class="card-header">Vaccination</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     

     <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/9" alt="" class=" card-img-top " >
            <h4 class="card-header">Health Advice</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/10" alt="" class=" card-img-top " >
            <h4 class="card-header">Childern care</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/11" alt="" class=" card-img-top">
            <h4 class="card-header">Health education</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  
 <!--end of row-->
  </div>
</div>

</div>


<div   class="section-testimonial">
  <div  class="row" >
      <div  class="col-md-2">
        <h2>  What people say about me</h2>
      </div>
      <div   class="col-md-10">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  </p> 
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but I want the cards to be stacked on the photo

Comment: I will be very grateful if you describe why is this happening?? I use the absolute position only in services section??

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements have no awareness of what's happening around them. When a page changes size, the elements don't move in relation to each other but rather in relation to their container and the values you've set for top, left etc. In your case you have added position:fixed, top:80% so in service area it just leaves 79% starts from 80%  @Razu

To know more:https://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/